# Как сделать ПРАВИЛЬНУЮ email рассылку новостей

Tags: php, email, рассылка, mandrill

Есть сайт, на `modx`. Будет, предположительно, около 1000 человек подписанных на новости. Как будет правильнее сделать ежедневную рассылку емейлов для них.

Пока подписчиков мало,Сейчас я в тупую перебираю емейлы в цикле и `MODXMailer`'ом(`PHPMailer`) через `sftp mandrill`'a рассылаю в `cron`'e. Я не уверен, что это будет работать при большем количестве подписчиков. Сделал ли я правильно, какие альтернативы?

Так вот вопрос, может быть есть какие-то сервисы подписок, на которые можно кинуть сгенерированное письмо и оно автоматически разошлёт это письмо собранным подписчикам?

И еще вопрос, какие адекватные (цена/качество) `sftp-сервисы` можете посоветовать в альтернативу `mandrill`?

Comment: Сервисы есть, вопрос в функциональности, которая вам нужна. Если у вас генерируется общий набор новостей для всей базы подписчиков — это один разговор, проще заплатить немного копеек и спать спокойно. Если же набор новостей уникален для каждого — придётся заморочиться.

Comment: Капс тут совершенно лишний.

Answer (score 1):

"Надо есть суп. Смотрел в сторону ложки, но не уверен, поможет ли."
*Единственный* смысл майлчимпа - это поддержание мэйллиста и рассылка по нему одинаковых для всех сообщений.
В то время как мандрилл - это рассылка одиночных сообщений, уникальных для каждого юзера.

Вопрос из серии "Уговорите меня использовать сервис, а то мне самому посмотреть лень".